# Java 6 File Input Output Stream (same file)

Tags: java, file, io, stream, java-6

I searched and looked at multiple questions like this, but my question is really different than anything I found.  I've looked at Java Docs.

How do I get the equivalent of this c file open:

```
stream1 = fopen (out_file, "r+b");
```

Once I've done a partial read from the file, the first write makes the next read return EOF no matter how many bytes were in the file.

Essentially I want a file I/O stream that doesn't do that.  The whole purpose of what I'm trying to do is to replace the bytes in an existing file in the current file.  I don't want to do it in a copy or make a copy before I do the Read->Write.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you're seeing is that when you write, the write appends to the end of the file, so now your file pointer is at EOF.  If you use RandomAccessFile as suggested below, then you can seek the position in the file, and write in the spot. Note that if you are replacing bytes, you're going to have a problem if you are writing more or less bytes than you are replacing, and need to deal with how you are going to shift the bytes which are after your replace spot.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Perception mentions, you can use a RandomAccessFile. Also, in some situations, a [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) may work better. I've used these to handle binary file data with great success.

EDIT: you can get a FileChannel from the RandomAccessFile object using `getChannel`.